# How to delete specific item in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a list of elements in database that looks like this:

```
User
---inventory(Map)
------items(List)
---------item0(Map)
---------item1(Map)
---------item2(Map)
```

I would like to delete one of the items based on item characteristics (e.g. `item.id`)

How can I do that with conditional expression? From what I've read you can only remove list elements using list indexes:

```
REMOVE MyNumbers[1], MyNumbers[3]
```

How can I do this with UpdateExpression/ConditionExpression instead?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the ConditionExpression is only for deciding whether to run/skip your whole update command.

In your case, you probably need to do a getItem to search for the index of remove target and remove the list item by index on updateItem.

You can also consider changing the List to Map and use the item's ID as key.

```
{
  inventory: {
    items :{
       1 : { name : item1...},
       2 : { name : item1...},
      }
  }
}
```

This way you can just use one db update command to remove the record.

```
remove inventory.items.1
```